# Python Global Variables - Not Defined?

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, global-variables

I'm running into an issue where a global variable isn't "remembered" after it's modified in 2 different functions. The variable `df` is supposed to be a data frame, and it doesn't point to anything until the user loads in the right file. This is similar to something I have (using `pandas` and `tkinter`):

```
global df

class World:

    def __init__(self, master):
        df = None
        ....

    def load(self):
        ....
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

    def save(self):
        ....
        df = df.append(...)
```

`save()` is always called after `load()`. Thing is, when I call `save()`, I get the error that "`df` is not defined." I thought `df` got its initial assignment in `init()`, and then got "updated" in `load()`? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to use `global df` *inside* the function that needs to modify the global variable. Otherwise (if writing to it), you are creating a local scoped variable of the same name inside the function and your changes won't be reflected in the global one.

```
p = "bla"

def func():
    print("print from func:", p)      # works, readonly access, prints global one

def func1():
    try: 
        print("print from func:", p)  # error, python does not know you mean the global one
        p = 22                        # because function overrides global with local name   
    except UnboundLocalError as unb:
        print(unb)
        
def func2():
    global p
    p = "blubb"                       # modifies the global p

print(p)
func()
func1()
print(p)
func2()
print(p)
```

Output:

```
bla   # global

print from func: bla    # readonly global

local variable 'p' referenced before assignment  # same named local var confusion

bla    # global
blubb  # changed global
```

Comment: Oh, so do I need to declare it every time I need to call it? There isn't a way for it to be "universally" remembered inside a class?

Comment: @Axioms if you want it to be available for all functions in a class you can make it a class variable. Other than that nothing much to do but to write it in every function needed

Comment: @Axioms  I prefer to not use globals at all - I mostly provide them as parameters to functions _or_ put them as member variables inside classes.

Comment: So if I set ``x = "hello"`` right after I declare a class (i.e. class variable), then would that ``x`` be ``"hello"`` in every function of that class?

Comment: @Axioms That would be a "static" Class-Variable, its shared between instances of that class, one changes it - all gets the change. Unless you need to create 20 different worlds, accessing the same `df` I would probably use a `self.df = None` inside the `__init__(self, ... )`, load it inside load `self.df = pd.read_csv(...)` etc.

Comment: Ah, guess I was confusing global variables with class variables. Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

for anyone coming here using python3 - try using nonlocal instead of global - a new construct introduced in python3 which allows you to mutate and read global variables in local scope

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the `global` keyword inside the function rather than outside. All the `df` that you have defined inside your function are locally scoped. Here is the right way -

```
df = pd.DataFrame() # No need to use global here

def __init__(self, master):
    global df # declare here
    df = None
....

def load(self):
    global df # declare here
    ....
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

def save(self):
    global df # declare here
    ....
    df = df.append(...)
```