# python guessing random number game not working, my names arent defined?

Tags: python, random, python-3.6

```
import sys, random
def rand():
    number = random.randint(0, 100)

def start():
    print("Entrez un nombre et essayez de faire correspondre le nombre aléatoire")
    guess= int(input())

def check():
    print (guess, number)
    if guess == number:
        print ("Les nombres sont le même!")
        print ("Recomence?")
        reawn=str(input())
        if reawn == "oui":
            rand()
            start()
            check()
    elif guess < number:
        print ("Ton nombre est plus grands que le nombre aléatoire!")
        print ("Essaye encore?")
        reawn=str(input())
        if reawn == "oui":
            start()
            check()
    elif guess > number:
        print ("Ton nombre est plus petit que le nombre aléatoire!")
        print ("Essaye encore?")
        reawn=str(input())
        if reawn == "oui":
            start()
            check()

rand()
start()
check()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "F:\Dominic\Python\rando.py", line 36, in 
>      check()
>    File "F:\Dominic\Python\rando.py", line 10, in check
>      print (guess, number)
>   NameError: name 'guess' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Global Variables - Not Defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715854/python-global-variables-not-defined)

Comment: The variable `guess` is local in both functions. This is why it is not recognised in `check()`, you are trying to use a variable which is not defined. Python is telling you that: `... NameError: name 'guess' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with the difference between **local** and **global** variables.

Here, in your function `check()`,  you're refering to the local variable `guess` which was only defined inside the other function `start()` and has not been defined in the context of the function `check()`. The function `check()` *does not know* the variable `guess` unless you specify what it's equal to inside the function.

What you could do in this case is:

```
import sys, random

def rand():
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    return number

def start():
    print("Entrez un nombre et essayez de faire correspondre le nombre aléatoire")
    guess= int(input())
    return guess

def check():

    number = rand()
    guess = start()

    print (guess, number)
    if guess == number:
        print ("Les nombres sont le même!")
        print ("Recomence?")
        reawn=str(input())
        if reawn == "oui":
            rand()
            start()
            check()
    elif guess < number:
        print ("Ton nombre est plus grands que le nombre aléatoire!")
        print ("Essaye encore?")
        reawn=str(input())
        if reawn == "oui":
            start()
            check()
    elif guess > number:
        print ("Ton nombre est plus petit que le nombre aléatoire!")
        print ("Essaye encore?")
        reawn=str(input())
        if reawn == "oui":
            start()
            check()

rand()
start()
check()
```

Here's [more information](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) on global and local variables from the Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `guess` is local to the function `start`. That means other functions don't see it. Consider returning it from `start`:

```py
def start():
    print("Entrez un nombre et essayez de faire correspondre le nombre aléatoire")
    guess= int(input())
    return guess
```

Same statement goes for your function `rand` (return the random number from the function).

Then change the definition of `check` as follows:

```py
def check(guess, number):
```

Finally, start the program as such:

```
check(start(), rand())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, variables defined outside of a function cannot be accessed inside a function. In the same way, variables defined inside of a function cannot be accessed outside the function or within another function. For example,

```
f="foo"
def function1():
    f="no foo"
    print(f)
def function2():
    f="not foo"

    print(f)
print(f)
function1()
function2()
```

If you run this program, it will come out to

```
foo
no foo
not foo
```

because the three `f`'s are either outside of the function or inside of a function, none of them are the same. In your program, you use `guess` and `number` in `check()` even though those variables were defined in `start()` and `rand()`. In order to be able to access these variables anywhere, at the start of your program, you must put

```
global guess
global number
```

in order to be able to access those variables from anywhere in the program. You must place these before the variable is defined. 
Another way you could go about to fix this is to do at the end of your program,

```
number = rand()
guess = start()
check(number, guess)
```

and in the `rand()` function, put `return number` at the end, and in the `start()` function, put `return guess` at the end. Also, you have to put, in the parameters for `check()`,

```
def check(number, guess)
```

This allows the `check()` function to get `number` and `guess` in its parameters without having to make the variables global.