# Calling versus defining global variables inside a Python function

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I'm relatively new to Python, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have two functions acting on a single variable `var`:

```
var = 8

def func1():
    print(var)

def func2():
    var += 1
    print(var)
```

`func2` will not function unless I define `var` as a global variable:

```
def func2():
    global var
    var += 1
    print(var)
```

What is the functionality that allows me to *call* global variables (as in `func1`) but does not allow me to *redefine* global variables without explicitly calling them first (as in `func2`)?

Comment: I hope this is only for educational purposes, otherwise, you are in for a very undefined behavior.

Comment: Anyway, does this answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715854/python-global-variables-not-defined

Comment: @DeepSpace: I see no `undefined behaviour` here. (Is there *any* undefined behaviour in python?)

Comment: I don't see you *calling* any variables. Did you mean access values?

Comment: @quamrana well, good luck  trying to debug this through a huge code base and trying to understand why `func1`'s outputs change between calls for "no apparent reason", especially if not single-threaded.

Comment: @DeepSpace, sorry, I come from a C++ background where (perversely) `undefined behaviour` has a precise definition. Anyway in the case of the snippets, that is what unit tests are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) explains the reasoning:

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within
>   the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly
>   declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains
>   this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a
>   bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was
>   required for all global references, you’d be using global all the
>   time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in
>   function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would
>   defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying
>   side-effects.